# What does the "Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source" error mean?

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, ado

I've gotten the "Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source" error (0x800a0e7b) in my classic asp page a couple of times, usually after I've just changed a stored procedure.

In the past, uninstalling and reinstalling the COM+ applications and a reset of IIS has seemed to fix this problem.  I'd assumed that the old ActiveConnection property was somehow being held in memory and the workaround was flushing it out.  Today, no such luck.

So my first question is, "What does this error actually mean?"  The second question is, "How do I fix it?"

I've tried consulting the following links, but as a COM+ novice this is currently over my head.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_20626178.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275490(BTS.10).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is most commonly associated with a stored procedure returning more than one result set, or returning rowcounts (try adding `set nocount on` at the top of the procedure.)

Did you make any recent changes to the database?  If so, those changes would be a good place to start looking.

P.S. I'm amazed that you have a COM+ application that's actually used in 2010. Phase that crap out as fast as you can :)

Comment: +1 for the P.S.  Although I think the answer to "What does this mean?" is "Time to move to .Net"

Comment: Moving to .NET is something I'd like to do, but it is hard to identify good places to refactor the existing codebase.

Comment: It is actually "set nocount on", not "set rowcount off".  It could also be caused by you expecting a proc to return an rs, and it doesn't, it just inserts and returns a status code or whatever.

Comment: I encountered this error also, but in my case the issue wasn't that I was returning more than one resultset, but in some scenarios the SP was returning no resultset. Fixing my SP so that it always returned exactly one resultset solved the problem.

Comment: I'm glad I searched for this answer, as the error message gives no hint whatsoever that the issue actually relates to 'set nocount on', and I was very confused as to why I could disconnect the recordset for some, but not all, of my stored procedures